# OData + Swagger. URL generation

Tags: .net-core, swagger, odata

In my Net 6 Web-API project I'm using OData and Swagger (it was added automatically when project was created).

It works out of the box, but there is an issue with some URLs generated by Swagger.

Here is my OData controller:

```
public class UsersController : ODataController
{
    // skipped for brevity

    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_dbContextRepo.Select<DbModel.User>());
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<User> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(_dbContextRepo.Select<User>().Where(u => u.Id == key));
    }
}
```

SwaggerUI output:

[image: SwaggerUI output]

When I try to run query that gets entity by Id from Swagger it fails because of wrong url.

[image]

By some reason Swagger generates query parameter and URL like on picture above. For OData URL has to be like this (path parameter, https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/):

```
https://localhost:7250/api/Users/1
```

In swagger.json parameter described as

[image]

Spent all day trying to figure this out. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution myself. I'm using OData 8 and it seems there is no need to mark method parameter as **[FromODataUri]**.

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<User> Get(int key)
{
    //...
}
```

Whithout it Swagger generates correct links.